# Lambda function - trimming or removing on a string return type VB - Casual query

Tags: vb.net, string, lambda

This isn't the world's most important query, actually it's a minor challenge I set myself at the end of a working day.

Basically I've converted a standard function to a Lambda but cannot quite replace the extension with a further Remove statement. So can anyone keen on Lambdas in VB explain how I can do this please?

```
 Property Inquery As Func(Of List(Of Integer), String) = Function(x) x.Aggregate("IN(", Function(current, id) current & (id & ",")).ToString.qtrim

<Extension()>
Function qTrim(str As String)
    qTrim = str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1) & ")"
End Function
```

As Meta-Knight was kind enough to provide me with a great answer, I think it fair to include the version I'm now using, with the ternary if statement included for others if they want it :)

```
  Property Inquery As Func(Of List(Of Integer), String) = Function(intList) If(intList.count > 0, "IN(" & String.Join(",", intList) & ")", "-1")
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You want to get rid of the extra method `qTrim`?

Comment: @Fuex Yes. I tried a various of .Remove variations but I can't quite hit on the right formula. It'd be cool to make it be one line :). Its also quite trivial really,I'd just like to know as it's a pure sytax thing rather than a proper problem to solve.

Comment: One line isn't always the best thing. Horizontal scrolling is very annoying.

Comment: @Styxxy it is a one off function, ain't that important and I'd just like to know; regardless of the horizontal thing. I like to fully get my tools I guess :P. I like options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use the simpler `String.Join` method:

```
Property Inquery As Func(Of List(Of Integer), String) = Function(intList) "IN(" & String.Join(",", intList) & ")"
```

With list containing numbers 1 through 5, I get the following output:

> IN(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Now THAT is precisely why I asked: I had the feeling there was a simple, elegant way-I just didn't know it. Thank you so much Meta-Knight :)